# Data bus with Java Flux API

Tags: reactive-programming, java-9, project-reactor

I was researching the Java Flux API when I noticed from some tutorials that you can only subscribe to one publisher. Yet, I see a use-case where having multiple publishers to a single subscribe is useful: some sort of a data/message bus.

The only solution I found is encapsulating an array of subscribers and 1 publisher inside the bus.

My question is, which is the correct approach from a reactive point of view to this problem?

---

I'm interested in solving this by implementing my own Publishers/Subscribers etc. (using the Java 9 `java.util.concurrent.Flow` API) This project is for learning purpouses, not for production.

Comment: It seems like you want to combine streams. There are plenty of operators allowing you to do this.

Comment: @abetteroliver I want to combine multiple publishers into one. What operators allow you to do this specifically? using the `java.util.concurrent.Flow` interfaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Reactor, an implementation of Java Publishers API. It has operators like concat(), merge() etc. to combine the Streams for a given Subscriber. 
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/